# Render PDF inline mobile and desktop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vite, pdf.js

**Hi**

i'm struggling browsing a pdf inline well on mobile and Desktop

env is vite 3.1.3, rails 7.0.4

Desktop i brought to run on all Browsers by `mozilla/pdfjs` but on mobile it doesnt show anything.

My Code is (on Rails)

`view`

```
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

`javascript`

```
// NPM
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'

window.showMozillaPdf = function () {

    var pdfData = atob(gon.doc_b64);
    
    console.log(pdfjsLib)
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '/documents/pdfjs_worker';

    console.log('pdf-part-2!')

    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
    loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
        console.log('PDF loaded');

        // Fetch the first page
        var pageNumber = 1;
        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
            console.log('Page loaded');

            var scale = 1.5;
            var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
            var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                console.log('Page rendered');
            });
        });
    }, function (reason) {
        // PDF loading error
        console.error(reason);
    });
}
```

The workers js (/documents/pdfjs_worker) i inserted from a controller because of mime type conflicts. This can be made nicer but it runs now.

This runs well on desktop but doesnt show anything on Mobile (iPhone 11 / Safari)

Has anyone experience with [mozilla/pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) on Mobile?

thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

**found it**

i had to change the way for getting the url to the worker asset:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf'
import workerUrl from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min?url'
...
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = workerUrl;
```

this replaces the `'/documents/pdfjs_worker'`

and i had to use the `/legacy/` for getting it to run on mobile.

See [vite-docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html)